# com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON while registering Selenium Grid Node to Hub

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

i installed selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar and run following command(as hube) on my machine A:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub
```

it runs successfuly.

then, on my machine B(as node) run following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.27:4444/grid/register
```

following logs produced. As you can see see, first it registered then it indicates it is not registered. How could be possible?

```
> 11:35:29.561 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown'
> 11:35:29.562 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
> 11:35:30.353 WARN - error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $
> 2017-07-23 11:35:30.417:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1343ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
> 11:35:30.568 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
> 11:35:30.568 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
> 11:35:30.572 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
> 11:35:30.572 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
> 11:35:30.573 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
> 11:35:30.575 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
> 11:35:30.585 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
> 2017-07-23 11:35:30.729:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
> 2017-07-23 11:35:30.828:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@70be0a2b{/,null,AVAILABLE}
> 2017-07-23 11:35:30.899:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@29176cc1{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:5555}
> 2017-07-23 11:35:30.900:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1827ms

> 11:35:30.900 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub

> 11:35:31.017 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.

> 11:35:31.017 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.27:4444/grid/register

> 11:35:31.062 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use

> 11:35:36.095 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $

> 11:35:41.123 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $

> 11:35:46.135 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $
```

Comment: What is your exact testing step? Do you want to start Selenium Grid Hub & Node? Hub & Node on same machine or different machine?

Comment: there are two different pc on same network. one is setup hub(it runs regularly). on second pc, i try to set up node but can't register to hub and logs above is generated.

Comment: So where are you exactly stuck? Able to start the Hub properly? Can you update the command used to start the Hub? Does the log messages indicate proper Hub startup? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB hub i started successful. problem is with node. it cannot connect. the log is generated after trying starting node.

Comment: If you are trying to start Selenium Grid Hub & Node both your commands need to be changed. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB so, what/where should be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Assuming that your requirement is to run the **`Selenium Grid Hub`** on default port `4444` and **`Selenium Grid Node`** on default port `5555` we need to configure and start them as follows:

1. Start the Selenium Grid Hub:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub
   ```
2. The following logs confirms your Selenium Grid Hub is running properly:

   ```
   2017-07-24 15:31:46.139:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @2757ms
   15:31:46.140 INFO - Nodes should register to http://192.168.0.107:4444/grid/register/
   15:31:46.140 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
   ```
3. Access the Selenium Grid Console through the URL:

   ```
   http://localhost:4444/grid/console
   ```
4. Start the Selenium Grid Node:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://<IP_GRID_HUB>:4444/grid/register
   ```

   I have used `localhost` so I used:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
   ```
5. The following logs confirms your Selenium Grid Node is running properly:

   ```
   15:35:44.939 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
   15:35:44.958 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
   15:35:44.958 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
   15:35:45.231 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
   ```
6. Access the Selenium Grid Console through the console URL to see the registered Node:

   ```
   http://localhost:4444/grid/console
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks, already i did same. but the problem is: 11:35:31.062 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use

11:35:36.095 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $                                                        as you can see, it connected but then suddently gives error and when checked hub, it looks not connected.

Comment: Can you consider to start the Selenium Grid Hub as per my Answer please? Thanks

Comment: when they work in same machine, they are OK. but, in real scenario, they are separated machines.

Comment: If the ports `4444` and `5555` are open on respective machines and there is no `ACL (Access Control List)` once you provide the real Hub IP in place of `<IP_GRID_HUB>` it will definitely work. Consider restarting both the `Hub` and the `Node` once. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by updating the version of chrome to latest (60) and the version of the chromedriver to latest.

It finally started working when I updated the version of the chromedriver on the hub side as well.

When I have some time I will be switching to [seleniumGridExtra](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras) which is supposed to manage the versions automatically.

My work log:
8/3/2017, 10:11:03 AM
  Still trying to get selenium running on the hub/node setup. It stopped 17 hours ago.

Updating all the files involved.

```
Latest chrome firefox and IE drivers.
Latest selenium version
Update chrome
rebooted machine
Updated chromeDriver on the hub..which seems silly.
  Suddenly working fine.
  Lessons learned: 
    Switch to selenium grid extras. They handle the version dependencies.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this but here what works for me. I run hub and node from same machine, I run hub and node from the window batch file. I run the hub first and make sure to leave the window opened then I run the grid. I didn't the connection issue since I started doing that